# What type of addressing does Tony Stark use in Iron Man 3?

Tags: marvel, iron-man-3, marvel-cinematic-universe

In the Iron Man 3 movie, when Stark uses the News Van to access the Internet, he is shown using an IP address which is not consistent with our real world standards. 
Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot from Iron Man 3 showing a computer interface]
<sup>Click image for full resolution</sup>

From my calculations the maximum number of bits required would be 10+10+6+4=30 (assuming that the last address is 999.999.99.9). We use 32 bit IPv4 addresses (max 255.255.255.255).
So my question is,

- Is it shown like this in this movie only to distinguish Marvel Universe with our Universe ?
- or Is there some other standard mentioned else where in any of the
  Comics, Cinema or TV Episode?

Comment: I think when movies or series shows something related to coding, I already assume that it's just a hype and it's wrong. Like sort of a Easter egg for us programmers to find. Like this on a show called arrow. It's just a for loop statement. http://imgur.com/qpkrwWn

Comment: You could try calculating for IPv6 though.

Comment: Its also not valid for IPv6, and the shortlived IPv5 used the same addressing as IPv4. Out of universe i'd guess they didn't want to use a real IP just in case someone decided that DOSing it would be fun

Comment: Thanks for [making my point](http://movies.stackexchange.com/a/2396/1326).

Answer (score 64, accepted):

There's a lot of real world history that shows the truth of a simple fact: if you put a real address or phone number on screen, someone will try to go there or call it, with irritating consequences for whomever lives there or has that number.

This is, for example, why phone numbers on American television are always 555-xxxx.

Similarly, IP addresses on screen tend to be technically invalid, usually by having one of the fields out of range; this is what I think we're seeing here ... IP4 movie style.

Comment: Either that or it's just that typical "because they don't know what they're writing about"... like hackers getting cars to explode or security cameras showing the exact same scenes/cuts only the audience had minutes before. :)

Comment: 867-5309 anyone?

Comment: There is a Wikipedia page about 555 numbers (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/555_%28telephone_number%29) and it lists 555-0100 to 555-0199 as the only range reserved for fictional numbers.

Comment: The best IP address they could use would be 127.0.0.1, instead of some made up value. It looks real because it is, and if there is any idiot hacker out there who doesn't know what it is will be in for a fun surprise when they try to do something to it.

Comment: @Xantec And for those recognizing a loopback address, it would have meant that Tony Stark is running the WHOLE Internet on this computer... IN A VAN! WITH A BOX OF SCRAPS!

Comment: @Xantec 127.0.0.1 looks likely familiar to any geek, and geeks are among the target audience of the movie. A better choice would be an address from those blocks reserved for documentation and examples, namely 192.0.2.0/24, 198.51.100.0/24 and 203.0.113.0/24.

Comment: @Philipp any address from 127.0.0.1 to 127.255.255.254 will go to loopback (i.e. 127.123.123.123). They could use any number there, not many geeks would recognize 127.343.131.343 as being loopback.

Comment: Someone somewhere would have recognized if they had used a reserved ip address in the private networks range. So 934.554.32.3 was not a bad idea at all.

Comment: @Eureka So? Perfectly in-character!

Comment: @Philipp I wasn't complaining :D

Comment: Sure geeks will recognize a loop back, but that is kind of the point after all. Geeks are going to pick it apart for having invalid addresses too ([eh-hem](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/40047/what-type-of-addressing-does-tony-stark-use-in-iron-man-3)). And Tony running the entire internet out of a van would sort of fit in with JARVIS' apparent distributed nature.

Comment: 127 anything would work (loopback). 10 or 192 anything would be okay too....no point in DOSing your girlfriend's laptop.

Comment: @Xantec: No, because 127.0.0.1 has a clear meaning and that meaning is obviously not the one intended in the scene. The address actually used has no inherent meaning at all (especially as it is invalid in _our_ reality) so it works fine!

Comment: If Tony Stark uses something in the 127.*.*.* range, wouldn't that mean, according to canon, he'd actually be connecting to his localhost? That wouldn't make any sense. What's more believable for canon purposes is that Tony has access to fictitious addresses.

Comment: I've seen the private block 10.0.0.0/8 addresses in movies a few times. The other widely used private block is 192.168.0.0/16, which I don't recall seeing in a movie. Another private block is 172.16.0.0/12, which I've never seen used in a movie or real life. The documentation and example /24 blocks @Philipp mentions would be ideal, for their relative obscurity.

Answer (score 11):

934.554.32.3, if the periods are replaced with semicolons, so 934:554:32:3:: becomes a valid IPv6 protocol address. (Also note: IPv6 is 4 digits in hexidecimal, and leading zeroes in each place may be omitted. Further, up to 8 such groups may be used.)

Note that 934:554:32:3:: is a valid but unassigned address at present.